# Background color not set on mobile

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

```css
.container.quote .quote-text {
  background: rgba(1, 10, 53, .8);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid overflow-hidden px-lg-0" style="margin: 6rem 0;">
  <div class="container quote px-lg-0">
    <div class="row g-0 mx-lg-0">
      <div class="col-lg-6 quote-text" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="img/carousel-1.jpg">
        <div class="h-100 px-4 px-sm-5 ps-lg-0 wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.1s" style="visibility: visible; animation-delay: 0.1s; animation-name: fadeIn;">
          <h2 class="text-white mb-4">Home | Commercial | Industrial</h2>
          <p class="text-light mb-5">test</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I use bootstrap 5

A kind of purple is displayed over image

```
<div class="container-fluid overflow-hidden px-lg-0" style="margin: 6rem 0;">
   <div class="container quote px-lg-0">
      <div class="row g-0 mx-lg-0">
         <div class="col-lg-6 quote-text" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="img/carousel-1.jpg">
            <div class="h-100 px-4 px-sm-5 ps-lg-0 wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.1s" style="visibility: visible; animation-delay: 0.1s; animation-name: fadeIn;">
               <h2 class="text-white mb-4">Home |  Commercial | Industrial</h2>
               <p class="text-light mb-5">test</p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

css part

```
.container.quote .quote-text {
  background: rgba(1, 10, 53, .8);
}
```

That work on pc... but not on iphone and android phone

On android photo that work if i choose display like computer release

any info why is not working?